# Is there an Airport Extreme Card 802.11ac?

Tags: wifi

I'm looking for the "Apple Airport Extreme Card 802.11ac", but I'm not sure if it exists, as I haven't been successful at finding it on my own.

Could anyone be able to tell me if such card exists for MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012)?

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths A lot, but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is the only Wireless-AC Airport card I could find:
[BCM94360CSAX 802.11AC BT4.0](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIABP54JX3330&cm_re=airport_card-_-9SIABP54JX3330-_-Product)

For the following models:

Macbook Pro rentina 2012 2013

A1425 A1398 A1502 MD212 MD213 MC975 MC976

2012 mid rmbp

2012 late rmbp

2013 early rmnp

Macbook Pro 13" A1502 2013 Retina

Compatible Subfamily

MacBook Pro "Core i5" 2.4 13" Late 2013

MacBook Pro "Core i5" 2.6 13" Late 2013

MacBook Pro "Core i7" 2.8 13" Late 2013

Compatible Model No

ME864LL/A* ME866LL/A

Comment: I found such card; It is the ucard from quickertek.com